# How can Michael use the body of Adam as a vessel when he was cremated in S04E19?

Tags: plot-explanation, supernatural

In [*Supernatural*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0460681/) season 04 episode 19 **Jump the shark** the body of Adam Winchester was cremated by Dean and Sam at the end. But in the final of season 05 **Swan song** he has been shown coming out of the grave. And later Michael possesses his body. How his body was in the grave?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The angels brought him back, body and all - which apparently they can do**.

You correctly point out that he was cremated by his brothers, Sam and Dean. In [Point of No Return](http://supernatural.wikia.com/wiki/Point_of_No_Return) we see his return:

He awakens in the ground near where his funeral pyre was. Castiel brings him to Bobby's house where he converses with Sam and Dean about *why* he is back:

> **DEAN** So why don't you just tell us everything? Start from the
>   beginning.
>   **ADAM** Well, I was dead and in Heaven. 'Cept it—it uh, kinda looked like
>   my prom and I was making out with this girl, her name was Kristin
>   McGee--
>   **DEAN** Yeah, that sounds like heaven. Did you get to third base?
>   **SAM** Just uh, just keep going.
>   **ADAM** Well, these…these angels, they popped out of nowhere, and they
>   tell me that I—I'm chosen.
>   **SAM** For what?
>   **ADAM** To save the world.
>   **DEAN** How you gonna do that?
>   **ADAM** Oh, me and some archangel are going to kill the devil.
>   **DEAN** What archangel?
>   **ADAM** Michael. I'm his uh, sword or vessel or something, I don't know.
>   // skipper dialogue
>   **ADAM** They said the fight might get pretty hairy, but it is the
>   devil, right? So we got to stop him.

So he was pulled from heaven to be the *vessel* of the archangel Michael. He had to be given form first, so the angels gave him his body back (which apparently they can do). He was then supposed to say yes to them - although we later learn this was all an elaborate ruse designed to lure Dean into a situation where he *had* to agree to being Michael's vessel.

Comment: You completely nailed it :D